# Publish an Ionic Event from javascript index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, events, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using the Ionic 2/3 framework and I have a Javascript callback in index.html.

I’m wondering if I can publish an event in Ionic when that is hit? It it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: We need more information, what event are you trying to publish? An ionic event? Do you have some code of what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

used window["ONESIGNAL VAR"], that worked.